# How to Save Virtual Currency?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, currency

I'm making an app using Unity3D, and I want to add some sort of virtual currency to my game.  Although, I cannot figure out how to implement a virtual currency so that a user can still play without internet.  I want the data to be hosted on my own database.  The problem with that comes when my user does not have internet.  How could I ***safely*** store a user's virtual currency when they go offline?  I have looked a lot and could not find anything.

Comment: You can't. If the game trusts the amount itself has stored, and that amount is tamperable (which any data stored on a user device is), then you cannot prevent tampering.

Comment: How do other games do it then?

Comment: AFAIK, they don't, or at least when they do, any detected gains are reversed, along with any illegitimate progress associated with the tampering.

Comment: Okay, wait.  I like to play Hill Climb Racing, and it stores your currency when you go offline.  It still saves it when I go back online.  Does that allow tampering at all?

Comment: Is that currency paid for? If it's just obtainable in-game, and since the game is singleplayer, I believe they don't even check for correctness, because it doesn't matter.

Comment: While it's possible to purchase the currency in Hill Climb Racing, its pure singleplayer nature and the ability to gain currency simply by playing means there's no incentive to validate anything. Another way is to create two virtual currencies, one is obtainable through playing, which you don't need to validate, and the other one is only available through IAPs, thus must be validated.

Comment: Ah, okay.  So, is it fine to store currency locally as long as it does not truly matter if a player changes it?  I was hoping to have some sort of IAP in my game, but I could go without if that would mean that my players would always need internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save datas on the device with SQlite database and then sync with the main server when it goes online.

Main server can be handled with Firebase or Google Games Services or other services.

You should add triggers to validate the amount to prevent hacking because datas stored on the device are not 100% safe.

Comment: Cool.  I might use this or I might not.  At this point it seems easier to store it locally, but I see there is a possibility that I could still have some sort of IAP.  :D